# Python script hangs on json.loads()

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to run a script for a class that takes a JSON payload to turn an led on or off.  I am able to get the payload and print out the topic and payload with print().  However, when running the script it hangs on json.loads().  Any help would be appreciated.

This is on a raspberryPi 3, python 3.5.3 with the grovepi board and led.  I ran the led_fade script that came with the grovepi, so I know the hardware works.

```
import time
import grovepi
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json


# Connect the LED to digital port D5
led = 5

# Set the blue LED pin to output mode
grovepi.pinMode(led,"OUTPUT")
time.sleep(1)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
"""Called each time the client connects to the message broker
:param client: The client object making the connection
:param userdata: Arbitrary context specified by the user program
:param flags: Response flags sent by the message broker
:param rc: the connection result
:return: None
"""
# subscribe to the LEDs topic when connected
client.subscribe("SNHU/IT697/leds")


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
"""Called for each message received
:param client: The client object making the connection
:param userdata: Arbitrary context specified by the user program
:param msg: The message from the MQTT broker
:return: None
"""
print(msg.topic, msg.payload)
payload = json.loads(msg.payload)
# the legal values for analogWrite are 0-255
grovepi.analogWrite(led, payload['blue'])
```

```
json payload that I am sending is:
mosquitto_pub -d -t "SNHU/IT697/leds" -m {\"blue\":0}

When running the script I get the results of the print(msg.topic, msg.payload):  SNHU/IT697/leds b'{"blue":0}'

I should see the led turn off if it receives a '0' value, but I believe that the script gets hung up on the payload=json.loads(msg.payload) statement.
```

Comment: This is my first time with python and raspberryPi so I apologize if my explanation is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

So I installed simplejson and ran my same code with 
import simplejson as json

And now it works!

Not sure whats wrong with the json that comes with Python, but at least I can get through my assignment.  I'm thinking that to fix the problem, I would have to reinstall Python??